# Find the variable generated in loop of php

Tags: php, html

I have this php code:

```
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
    echo 'Question'.$i.'</br>';
    echo 'Answer..</br>';
    echo '<form action="" method="POST">';
    echo '<textarea name="answer"></textarea>';
    echo '</br><button name="answer_button'.$i.'"><b>Answer</b></button>';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

Now I want to get the question number for which the `answer_button` is clicked.

Closest I could get was this:

```
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {   
    echo 'Question'.$i.'</br>';
    echo 'Answer..</br>';
    echo '<form action="" method="POST">';
    echo '<textarea name="answer"></textarea>';
    echo '</br><button name="answer_button"><b>Answer</b></button>';
    echo '</form>';
    if(isset($_POST['answer_button'])) {
         echo $i;
         break;
     }
}
```

This gives me Question number but it will not print other questions in loop once the button is clicked.

Is there no solution without using javaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the html markup to use an "array notation":

```
echo '<button name="answer_button['.$i.']" type="submit">Answer</button>';
```

That will cause php to populate an array when receiving back the form which you can examine:

```
<?php
// ...
if(isset($_POST['answer_button']) && is_array($_POST['answer_button'])) {
    $id = array_shift(array_keys($_POST['answer_button']));
    // ...
}
```

This allows to have multiple such buttons in a single form and detect which one has actually been clicked. It works, because $_POST will contain an array with a single element with key as in `$id`, which you can easily examine yourself with a `var_dump($_POST);` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

This should work :

```
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {   
    echo 'Question'.$i.'</br>';
    echo 'Answer..</br>';
    echo '<form action="" method="POST">';
    echo '<textarea name="answer"></textarea>';
    echo '</br><button name="answer_button'.$i.'"><b>Answer</b></button>';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';
}

for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
    if(isset($_POST["answer_button".$i])) {
        echo $i;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It does not print the other questions. No offence but by closest solution I gave in question was better. See if you can modify that for better.

Comment: you sure? ı tested it, it writes all questions and finally the clicked button index.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your looking for.

***CODE***

```
<?php
echo '<form action="" method="POST">';
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    echo 'Question: ' . $i . '<br>';
    echo 'Answer..<br>';
    echo "<textarea name='answer[$i]'> </textarea></br>";
    echo "</br><button name='answer_button[$i]' value='BtnPushed'>   <b>Answer</b></button><br>";
    if (! empty($_POST['answer_button'][$i])) echo "Last Answer: {$_POST['answer'][$i]}<br>";
    echo '<hr>';
}
echo '</form>';
```

### ***Results***

[image: Results]